# Email style changes in different applications

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I'm currently using `nodemailer` to send emails to customers who request to change their password on my website. However, the styling works well for the default windows `mail` app but different when using [gmail](https://mail.google.com), different again when using the gmail app for mobile.
My question is how would I go on making a simple box with a logo and a reset link work with all mail applications?
My Code:

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
async function main() {
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com', //gmail smtp server
        port: 587, //gmail port
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: require('./misc/auth').email,
            pass: require('./misc/auth').token
        },
    });
    if (req.query.type === 'forgot-password' && data.from) {
        let name = '';
        db.fetchAll().forEach(d => {
            if (d.ID !== 'login') return;
            d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d.data[0]));
            if (d.email === data.from) name = d.fName.toString();
        });
        function makeid(length) {
            let result = '';
            let characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            let charactersLength = characters.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
            }
            return result;
        }
        let link = `${req.headers.referer.split(req.headers.host)[0]}${req.headers.host}/reset/${makeid(20)}?token=${makeid(15)}`;
        setTimeout(async function() {
            if (name === '') return res.json({ error: 'Internal Error' });
            await transporter.sendMail({
            from: `${require('./misc/auth').name} <${require('./misc/auth').email}>`,
            to: data.from,
            subject: 'Reset Your Password',
            text: '',
            html:
                `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` +
                `<style>` +
                `a {text-decoration: none; color: black; } .text-center { text-align: center; } .text { font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; } .title { font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; } .sub-title { font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; } .body { display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: auto; } .header { border-radius: 5px; border: 5px solid black; padding: 50px 90px; } button { display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: aut; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 5px; border-color: black; }` +
                `</style>` +
                `<body>` +
                    `<div class="body">
                        <div class="header">
                            <img class="logo" src="${req.headers.referer.split(req.headers.host)[0]}${req.headers.host}/style/images/logo.webp" width="200px" height="200px">
                            <div class="text title text-center"><h1>Website Name</h1></div>
                            <span class="text">Hi  ${name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase()},</span><br>
                            <div class="text sub-title text-center"><h1>Forgot your password?</h1></div><br>
                            <a href="${link}">
                                <button>Reset Your Password</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>` +
                `</body></html>`
            });
            res.json({ response: 'Success' });
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email HTML must account for numerous clients and browsers. Many older clients will not render your email properly due to the fact that they have not evolved with web standards.

In its current state, your HTML is not built responsively and could benefit from adding responsiveness, meta tags, and conditional statements for outlook.

[Here is a good resource](https://litmus.com/community/learning/24-how-to-code-a-responsive-email-from-scratch) to help you adjust your code. Additionally, you can use a framework like [MJML](https://mjml.io/) to build a valid template with ease.